# Increase the bitrate of an already encoded video?

Tags: video

I am very new so if something here doesn't make sense i am sorry. I am using OBS and the recording i did is something i have to keep, it is very important to me. But for a weird reason it defaulted to a low bitrate, so when i looked at the video after i was finished recording it , i almost couldn't see anything. Can i increase the bitrate after this, to make it have way better quality? I have tried a few different softwares but i didn't see a difference.

Comment: This is what it looks like, https://gyazo.com/366f57d895c9293400da162b691b534e. This is probably not recoverable.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, but there is no way to get more detail in that video without physically replaying the game and re-recording real gameplay.

Comment: If it was possible, all video players would do that when playing the video. We'd also be using the lowest possible bitrate for everything, because why waste disk space for high bitrate files of you can get the same quality out of low bitrate files.

Answer (score 2):

Do not do this. Re-encoding will only *lose* more data, not somehow make more quality appear where there is none. The encoders have no idea how to rebuild *more* detail without somehow being given more information to begin with.

The encoder will decode a noisy video, get a frame that is full of noise, and then try to recreate that noise.

At best using a higher bandwidth to re-encode will faithfully recreate the current noisy video, and use more space to do so. Video codecs are "lossy" and will use approximations to recreate what they see, and while a higher bitrate will more accurately recreate the incoming video, they will **always** lose some quality.

The more you reencode a video the worse the quality will become. See Wikipedia [Generation Loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss).

Comment: In short: garbage in, garbage out.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create something from nothing.

If the additional data you would like to see is not there, you cannot create it magically from thin air. All any re-encoding can do for you is make more bits out of the bits you have.